# sqlite3 How to change a field conditionally in a joined table (using CASE..END together with JOIN)?

Tags: sqlite, join, case

I have two tables "object" and list" `joined` by:

```
$cmd="SELECT *  FROM object LEFT JOIN list ON (object.id=list.imgref AND list.persoon={$_SESSION['id']})"
    ." WHERE (owner=0 OR owner={$_SESSION['id']})  ";
```

This works as I intended.
Example:

```
table object
id cat owner
1  a   0
2  b   0
3  c   0
4  d   2
5  e   88
6  f   0

table list
lid imgref catlist persoon
1   2       AA      2
2   3       BB      2
3   4       CC      2
4   3       DD      33


result of LEFT JOIN
id cat owner | lid imgref catlist persoon
1   a  0
2   b  0       1     2     AA      2
3   c  0       2     3     BB      2
4   d  2       3     4     CC      2
6   f  0
```

Now in the resulting combined table I want the field "object.cat" conditionally changed to  the value of "list.catlist", in `sqlite3-speak`:

`WHEN list.persoon={$_SESSION['id']} THEN object.cat=list.catlist END`

For example (notice column "cat"):

```
id cat owner | lid imgref catlist persoon
1   a   0
2   AA  0       1     2     AA      2
3   BB  0       2     3     BB      2
4   CC  2       3     4     CC      2
6   f   0
```

Unfortunately the following statement gives an error:

```
$cmd="SELECT *  FROM object LEFT JOIN list ON (object.id=list.imgref AND list.persoon={$_SESSION['id']})"
    ." CASE WHEN list.persoon={$_SESSION['id']} THEN object.cat=list.catlist END"
    ." WHERE (owner=0 OR owner={$_SESSION['id']})  ";
```

I would appreciate any help to find the correct formulation.

Comment: I'm uncertain what you really mean/want. For clarity please [edit] the question and add the table definitions (as `CREATE TABLE` statements), sample data (as `INSERT INTO` statements) and the desired result with that sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CASE` expression must appear in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT o.id,
  CASE WHEN l.persoon={$_SESSION['id']} THEN l.catlist ELSE o.cat END AS cat,
  o.owner, l.* 
FROM object o LEFT JOIN list l 
ON (o.id=l.imgref AND l.persoon={$_SESSION['id']})
WHERE (o.owner=0 OR o.owner={$_SESSION['id']})
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b8z3iqUvzPdSkUudS7pe8z/1).
Results (for `{$_SESSION['id']} = 2`):

```
| id  | cat | owner | lid | imgref | catlist | persoon |
| --- | --- | ----- | --- | ------ | ------- | ------- |
| 1   | a   | 0     |     |        |         |         |
| 2   | AA  | 0     | 1   | 2      | AA      | 2       |
| 3   | BB  | 0     | 2   | 3      | BB      | 2       |
| 4   | CC  | 2     | 3   | 4      | CC      | 2       |
| 6   | f   | 0     |     |        |         |         |
```

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot, forpas, for your helpful correction..............Eke

Comment: I didn't know about this, but I will do so in the future. Thanks again....Eke